# Add NLP NGRAM/Term results to a new column in existing data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, nlp

Good evening Stackers! I have another doozy for you :)

I have an excel file with approx 54k rows, and in this file, I have a column called "short description", this is the "short description" of an end users IT issue -  "I can't print", "I am unable to open X from server Y", etc. I am using NLP to find the most common "words and phrases" identified in the data-set or in the Short Description... here is a look into what that output looks like:
[image]

To get to this point, I have created a corpus from my short description, I have done all of the "cleaning", meaning, changing everything to lower case, removed stop words, white space, etc.  The output in the image above was done by using term_stats(corpus, ngrams = 3:3)

Now what I would like to do, for example, if you look at UPC Scanning issues from the image above, I would like to create a new column in the "db" data-source called 'phrase', and for every row that UPC Scanning issues was found in the short description, I simply want to add that in a new row of the new phrase column.. like a one to one relationship if you will. Trying to explain myself further, if short description row 1  said "I am having issues with my upc scanning platform" the new column "phrase' row one would be "upc scanning issues"

This is how i am building my corpus, and other parts of the script:

```
###### GET RID OF FUNKY CHARS ########
db$SHORT_DESCRIPTION <- sapply(db$SHORT_DESCRIPTION,function(row) iconv(row, "latin1", "ASCII", sub=""))

###### CREATE CORPUS ########
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(db$SHORT_DESCRIPTION))

###### INSPECT CORPUS ########
inspect(corpus[1:20])

###### TRANSFORM/MANIPULATE TEXT IN CORPUS ########
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, c("csd","CSD","please","request","service","servic","active","activ","resourc","reset","8000","self","please",'compucom","self","pleas","notif","csdplease","caller","record","issue","temp","csdemail","csdneed","csdact"))
str_replace_all(db$SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "[[:punct:]]", " ")
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)

##### CREATE PHRASES #####
phrases <- term_stats(corpus, ngrams = 3)
phrases

##### NOW THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK ######
db$phrases <- phrases????? 
#I get an error saying that phrases contains aprpox 200k rows and my data set only containts 54k rows..
```

I want to take the results of phrases, create a column in the db dataset, and add the results of phrases from above into that column.

Sorry for the image, but it's the easiest way for me to show the output of the phrases line that I created.

Comment: Please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). And show your (minimal) code until where you get stuck. There are lots of ways to create a corpus. You can always use a dataset that comes with a package instead of your own dataset. And don't use images to show data.

Comment: Let me see how I can post the parts of the script, I am getting an error saying that my comment is too long by 500+ characters.

Comment: @phiver, I have modified my post, please review if you have some time.  I am sure it has to be some kind of loop that I need to build, but I have 100% no idea how to do this.

Comment: The problem you run into is that if you have 4 words in a sentence, a tri-gram will create 2 tri-grams of this. you have 54k rows, to about 200k tri-grams means about 6 words per row on average. Mapping 200k to 54k is not going to work. You will need to figure out how to diminish the amount of n-grams you are creating. You might want to think about removing versions. If you look at the first 2 lines of your terms they look to be created from the same order of terms in sentences. So which one are you going to use?

Comment: Or you could transform your phrases to wide format, so you add multiple phrases after each of your row.